# fix height of scrollbar in nested recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollbar

I have a horizontal `Recyclerview` inside another horizontal `Recyclerview`. Now I want to show the `scrollbar`. But the height of the scrollbar is changing as I scroll. I want to have a fixed height of the scrollbar as I scroll. How can I achieve that? I have a custom `LinearLayoutManager`. But it is not working properly. Any better solution to this problem?

```
class CoolLayoutManager(context: Context,orientation: Int,
  reverseLayout: Boolean) : LinearLayoutManager(context,orientation,
    reverseLayout) {

  init {
    isSmoothScrollbarEnabled = true
  }

  override fun computeHorizontalScrollExtent(state: State): Int {
    val count = childCount
    return if (count > 0) {
      SMOOTH_VALUE * 3
    } else 0
  }

  override fun computeHorizontalScrollRange(state: State): Int {
    return Math.max((itemCount - 1) * SMOOTH_VALUE, 0)
  }

  override fun computeHorizontalScrollOffset(state: State): Int {
    val count = childCount

    if (count <= 0) {
      return 0
    }
    if (findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == itemCount - 1) {
      return Math.max((itemCount - 1) * SMOOTH_VALUE, 0)
    }

    val widthOfScreen: Int
    val firstPos = findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
    if (firstPos == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
      return 0
    }
    val view = findViewByPosition(firstPos) ?: return 0
// Top of the view in pixels
    val top = getDecoratedTop(view)
    val width = getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(view)
    widthOfScreen = if (width <= 0) {
      0
    } else {
      Math.abs(SMOOTH_VALUE * top / width)
    }
    return if (widthOfScreen == 0 && firstPos > 0) {
      SMOOTH_VALUE * firstPos - 1
    } else SMOOTH_VALUE * firstPos + widthOfScreen
  }


  companion object {
    private const val SMOOTH_VALUE = 100
  }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the layout:
[image]

Comment: can you provide screenshot of your view?

Comment: @HardikChauhan added.

Comment: Thanks, but i meant with the scrolllbars to understand the exact issue.

Comment: The problem is the parent `recyclerview` is holding two `recyclerview`. So I have enabled the scrollbar for parent `recyclerview`. So the items of the parent `recyclerview` are of different width. It's resizing the scrollbar. @HardikChauhan